# Does League of Legends track Co-op vs. AI?

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends when you play "Co-op vs. Al" do your minion and Champion kills get added to your overall total on your profile?

Answer (score 7):

If by overall total, you mean this screen:

[image]

Then the answer is **no**. These only track the total in Normal games (PvP).

There is currently no tracking Co-op vs. AI kills/Wins in your profile stats, and I can't find anything from Riot saying that they plan to include this feature. It would be nice though.

(*These stats are from someone who's been playing since closed beta. I used them because mine are so embarrassing*)

Comment: I was wondering about the stats.  I was going to be *really* embarassed by mine otherwise. :)

Comment: You can how ever, after the coop match is complete see how many wins and losses you have in coop. Like with normal games, but then only the coops. Also you can hover over your teammates names and see the wins they have for coop matches. But that is about it.